# Wikitext editor for OS X

Tags: mediawiki, wiki, wikitext

Could anyone suggest a Wikitext editor for OS X?  My company uses MediaWiki extensively and I am looking for more of an IDE-like text editor I can use offline.

Answer (score 4):

I use the excellent and now free and open source [TextMate](https://github.com/textmate/textmate) with the [MediaWiki bundle](https://github.com/textmate/mediawiki.tmbundle) for editing MediaWiki markup. I invoke it using the [It's All Text](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/its-all-text/) Firefox Extension which will automatically open up text mate from within the browser and copy in the text. Then when you save from textmate, It's All Text also automatically copies the text back into your browser. I'm on OS X Lion with Firefox 14 and the latest TextMate nightly build.

There are of course other options. For a comprehensive list, see [the wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia%3aText_editor_support).

Answer (score 0):

There are several vim plugins available for wikitext.

Comment: There's always MacVim! I use it daily for markup-like languages: http://cloud.gf3.ca/9FHF

Answer (score 0):

LibreOffice works in Mac as well. You can export from any document to MediaWiki (wikitext) format.

Answer (score 0):

In 2020 I'm using Atom with the language-markdown package. I save the files as .md and then syntax highlighting takes effect. Then I can also define a project locally and manage it using Git.

[image: Atom with Markdown syntax]

Comment: atom's language-markdown is for Markdown, not for MediaWiki wikitext, right?  I can't seem to find any wikitext support in language-markdown.